# Como submeter dados de um array JS pelo PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Eu tenho um form que possui uma table que será gerada conforme o usuário for adicionando elementos nela através do botão "Adicionar". (Um cliente pode ter vários endereços)

Como serão gerados vários dados, irei precisar de um array. A única forma que sei fazer isso é usando javascript.

Como faço para pegar estes dados do javascript e "jogar" eles no meu botão submit do formulário? Existe alguma forma de eu fazer isso usando somente PHP?

Comment: Olá, bem vindo ao **StackOverflow PT**. Aproveite para fazer o [Tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para perceber melhor como funciona o site. Se achar que melhora a sua questão, coloque o código onde esteja a precisar de ajuda.

Comment: Seu javascript gera o formulário de acordo com o clique do usuário no botão adicionar. Pegue os campos no PHP normalmente pelo POST. Qual o problema ?

Comment: Por exemplo, se em cada "Adicionar" do usuário, gerar uma row para a tabela, como faço para capturar cada dado gerado?

Comment: @user124006 Seu "adicionar" não gera inputs ?

Answer (score 1):

Existe várias formas de fazer isso, seria mais interessante se você disponibiliza-se o código atual.

De qualquer forma olhe o código abaixo. Talvez posso de da uma luz sobre oque fazer. Caso isso não ajude me informe que posso pensar em algo para te ajudar.

```
<?php 

print_r($_POST);

?>
<div>

    <form method="post">

        <div>
            <label> Campo 1 </label>
            <input type="text" name='campo[]'>
        </div>

        <div>
            <label> Campo 2 </label>
            <input type="text" name='campo[]'>
        </div>

        <div>
            <label> Campo 3 </label>
            <input type="text" name='campo[]'>
        </div>

        <button> Enviar </button>

    </form>

</div>
```

O resultado para o furmulario acima é:

```
Array
(
    [campo] => Array
        (
            [0] => 11
            [1] => 22
            [2] => 33
        )

)
```

Observe que ao adicionar o '[]' no final atributo 'name' do input o PHP vai entender que se trata de um array. Ao duplicar os campos do endereço você tera como resultado por exemplo um campo CEP sendo um array no PHP:

```
Array
    (
        [cep] => Array
            (
                [0] => 74063-470
                [1] => 75266-392
            )

    )
```